# Advanced replacement for UNIX/GNU "find" (command-line file search)

Tags: linux, file-management, command-line, search, shell-scripting

GNU's default file search utility for the command line [`find`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/) has a ton of options, but is still missing some - in my opinion - essential features, [like sorting](https://superuser.com/questions/294161/unix-linux-find-and-sort-by-date-modified). It's also a hassle to use sometimes.

In the same way that [`ack`](http://beyondgrep.com/) can be seen as a modern, advanced version of `grep` with a cleaner interface, can anyone recommend a similar replacement for `find`?

(Bonus points if it also comes with functionality similar to `locate`, i.e. indexed search.)

Comment: What about GUI ? , search monkey ?

Comment: @totti I'd prefer terminal applications because they usually allow you to quickly process the results you got further (e.g. additional filtering via ``sed``, integration into a script, etc.). But thanks for your suggestion, I will have a look at that one as well.

Comment: For GUI's, catfish works ok, I'm not sure about sed filtering though. But with regular find you can always `| sort`, it can even handle NUL-terminated names with `--files0-from=-`

Answer (score 4):

Take advantage of the shell! While no shell equals `find`'s advanced use cases, **zsh** can handle many, and even bash can handle the basic ones.

The fundamental feature of `find` is to traverse directories recursively. This feature is found in modern interactive shells. In bash, ksh93, zsh and fish, the **[glob pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) `**`** stands for a subdirectory at any depth. Thus `echo **/*` lists the same files as `find .` (except that `**/*` skips dot files by default), `echo **/*.txt` lists the same files as `find -name '*.txt`, etc. All shells sort wildcard matches. To run a command, you simply pass it the arguments as usual: instead of `find -name '*.txt' -exec ls -ld {} +`, you can just run `ls -ld **/*.txt`.

In bash, the `**` pattern needs to be enabled with [`shopt -s globstar`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin). Put this line in your `~/.bashrc`. In ksh93, the `**` pattern needs to be enabled with `set -o globstar`. In [fish](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#expand-wildcard) and [zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Recursive-Globbing), `**` is always enabled.

The shell syntax is more straightforward when you want to execute a command on the files. If you want to list the file names, `echo` separates them with spaces. If you want one file per line instead, you can use

```
printf '%s\n' **/*
```

This is a bit cumbersome to type, but you can define an alias, e.g.

```
alias p='printf %s\\n'
```

Ksh defines additional wildcard pattern syntax that gives wildcard matching the same expressive power as regular expression, plus a shortcut for negation. In bash, these patterns can be enabled with `shopt -s extglob`; in zsh, with `setopt ksh_glob`. Zsh has [additional operators](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators) with the same expressive power, which need to be enabled with [`setopt extended_glob`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-EXTENDED_005fGLOB) (do put `setopt extended_glob` in your `~/.zshrc`). Here are some examples of zsh extra patterns (many requiring `setopt extended_glob`):

- `*-<8-15>.txt` — match files with a numeric suffix between 8 and 15 followed by `.txt`. For example this includes `foo-8.txt` and `foo-08.txt` but not `foo-100.txt` or `foo-a.txt`. Nothing like this in `find`.
- `*.txt~foo.txt` — matches all `.txt` files except `foo.txt`. Like `find -name '*.txt' ! -name foo.txt`.
- `*.(cc|cxx)` — match `.cc` and `.cxx` files. Like `find \( -name '*.cc' -o -name '*.cxx' \)`.

Beware that in bash ≤4.2 and fish, `**/` traverses **symbolic links** to directories (like `find -L`). Ksh93, bash ≥4.3 and zsh are safe: `**/` only traverses directories. In zsh, `***/` traverses symbolic links to directories as well.

In most shells, wildcard matching is only based on the file name. The only way to match files by type is to add `/` at the end of the pattern, which restricts the matches to directories (including symbolic links). **Zsh** is unique in offering a way to match files by type and other metadata: [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers). You can even embed arbitrary code in glob qualifiers to run code to filter and rewrite matches, though when things get that complex, the syntax is arguably worse than `find`. Here are a few examples of simple uses of glob qualifiers. Recall that this is a zsh-only feature.

- `**/*(.)` — all regular files, like `find -type f`
- `*(.)` — all regular files in the current directory, like `find -maxdepth 1 -type f`
- `**/*(.*)` — executable regular files, like `find -type f -executable`
- `**/*(U)` — files owned by the invoking user, like `find -user $USER`
- `**/*(.m-2)` — regular files modified less than 2 days ago, like `find -type f -mtime -2`
- `*(/^F)` — empty subdirectories of the current directory, like `find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -empty`

You can also control how the matches are **sorted** with a glob qualifier. For example `echo *(.m-2om)` prints the names of the files that were modified in the last 2 days from youngest to oldest.

Shells omit **[dot files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory)** from wildcard matches unless the leading `.` is present in the pattern. This can be controlled via the `FIGNORE` variable in ksh, the [`GLOBIGNORE`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-pathname-expansion) variable in bash, or the [`glob_dots`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-GLOB_005fDOTS) option in zsh. In zsh, you can use the `D` glob qualifier to include dot files. Unlike other shells, zsh will never include `.` or `..` in wildcard matches.

If you want to **prune** some directories from the traversal, in zsh, you can [put slashes under a Kleene star](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71881/excluding-a-directory-name-in-a-zsh-recursive-glob). For example, `find -name .svn -prune -o -type f` becomes `(^.svn/)#*(.)`

The `find` command remains superior if there are **very many matches**, because it prints files as soon as they're found, and executes commands individually (`-exec … \;`) or in batches (`-exec … +`). Since the shell sorts matches, it can't start displaying them until it's gathered them all, which can take a long time. Recent versions of zsh have the `Y` glob qualifier to stop after a number of matches, e.g. `**/*.txt(Y1)` looks for a `.txt` file anywhere under the current directory and stops once it's found one.

If you want to execute a command on the files and the shell complains that the command line is too long, you can still use [`xargs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs). Zsh offers [zargs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zargs) as an alternative.

```
find -exec mycommand {} +
find -print0 | xargs -0 mycommand
printf %s\\0 **/* | xargs -0 mycommand
zargs -- **/* -- mycommand
```

I'm not aware of anything that integrates `find` with `locate`.

Comment: Excellent write-up, thank you very much! I've been thinking about trying zsh for some time, now I'm convinced it's a good idea. For day-to-day usage it seems like you can get to the point of what you're trying to do more quickly than in bash.